# Android - Converting compressed Bitmap (gzip) to Base64 causing data loss

Tags: android, bitmap, base64, gzip

I am trying to convert a bitmap to base64 using gzip.

I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379904/how-to-convert-an-image-to-a-base64-string-with-gzip-android?rq=1) but I got this error **GZIP cannot be resolved or is not a field**

My solution below is working but the image is being cut at the bottom

[image]

this is my code:

```
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("\path\to\file.jpg");
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        GZIPOutputStream gzipOstream=null;
        try {
            gzipOstream=new GZIPOutputStream(stream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,  gzipOstream);
        byte[] byteArry=stream.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArry,  Base64.NO_WRAP);
        try {
            gzipOstream.close();
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

could this code make the image lose data or is it something on the server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After calling `mBitmap.compress();` call `gzipOstream.flush();` this guarantees that the output byte stream contains everything. Then your `toByteArray();` will get the currently missing data.

Try this:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("\path\to\file.jpg");
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    GZIPOutputStream gzipOstream = null;
    try {
        gzipOstream = new GZIPOutputStream(stream);
        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, gzipOstream);
        gzipOstream.flush();
    } finally {
        gzipOstream.close();
        stream.close();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    stream = null;
}
if(stream != null) {
    byte[] byteArry=stream.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArry, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    // do something with encodedImage
}
```

Comment: that didn't work  for me. still getting the gray on the image

Comment: you're my hero :) that worked perfectly. thank you very much.

Comment: Your welcome. Thanks @TheIronMarx for your formatting. I approved it. I was on the train when I edited the code ;) mobiles suck for that. I was just about to edit edit it and you'd beat me too it ;)